# Determinant Multiple

Tags: matrices, determinant

I keep getting a multiple of the actual value of the determinant of matrices after performing row operations to reduce it to an upper triangular matrix. Any ideas why this might happen?[For an easy 3x3 for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8emz1.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please edit your question to show us just what you did. Then we might be able to help. Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: It would be good if you include an example for a $2\times 2$-matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Each and every Row/Column operations will affect the value of the determinant depends on the constant that we are multiplying for the row.

For example,

$R_1 -> R_1 - R_2$ will not affect the value of the determinant.

But,  $R_1 -> 2R_1 - R_2$ will double the value of the determinant as we are multiplying the $R_1$ by 2.

Even the operation $R_1 -> R_2 - R_1$, will actually affect the determinant value as $-1 * Determinant$

So, At each steps whenever we are doing such operations, we should ensure that we have the Same Co-efficient with sign on both the side. If you want to do the operations by multiplying with some constants, then we should take the constant outside as a divisor.

For example,

$R_1 -> R_1 - R_2$  --> $Actual\,Determinant = Determinant\,\,after\,Row/Column\,operation$

$R_1 -> R_2 - R_1$  --> $Actual\,Determinant = \frac{Determinant\,\,after\,Row/Column\,operation}{-1}$

$R_2 -> -3R_2 - 5R_1$  --> $Actual\,Determinant = \frac{Determinant\,\,after\,Row/Column\,operation}{-3}$

In Your attached example,

At first step you have done $C_1 -> 5C_2 - 6C_1$ --> $Actual\,Determinant = (1/-6)\,(Det)$

At Second step you have done $R_3 -> R_1 + R_3$ --> $Actual\,Determinant = (1/1)\,(Det)$

At Third step you have done $R_2 -> 2R_2 - R_3$ --> $Actual\,Determinant = (1/-1)\,(Det)$

You got your determinant value as 162 after these operations.

So,
$Actual\,Determinant = \frac{162}{(-6)(1)(-1)}\,=27$